# Game pause that turns off a key listener function

Tags: javascript, events, key

I am messing with a very simple game that has a key listener for the left and right arrows.

When I pause the game with the spacebar, I want those listeners to do nothing while the game is paused. I was thinking I could implement this into the pause function or when the spacebar is heard by the key listener. I am relatively new to this and just plain don't know how to do this.

```
function keyListener(e){
   if(!e){
      //for IE
      e = window.event;
   }
   if(e.keyCode==37 && paddleLeft > 0){
      //keyCode 37 is left arrow
      paddleLeft -= 25;
      paddle.style.left = paddleLeft + 'px';
   }
   if(e.keyCode==39 && paddleLeft < 925){
      //keyCode 39 is right arrow
      paddleLeft += 25;
      paddle.style.left = paddleLeft + 'px';
   }
   if(e.keyCode==32){
      pause();
   }
}
```

And here is the pause function:

```
function pause(){
   if(!gamePaused){
      timer = clearTimeout(timer);
      gamePaused = true;
   } else if(gamePaused) {
      timer = setTimeout(start(),1000/50);
      gamePaused = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(e.keyCode==37 && paddleLeft > 0 && !gamePaused){
      //keyCode 37 is left arrow
      paddleLeft -= 25;
      paddle.style.left = paddleLeft + 'px';
   }
   if(e.keyCode==39 && paddleLeft < 925 && !gamePaused){
      //keyCode 39 is right arrow
      paddleLeft += 25;
      paddle.style.left = paddleLeft + 'px';
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a **!gamePaused** condition in left/right ifs.

If you disable keyListener you cannot unpause your game anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may want to consider maintaining a stack of key listeners. Spacebar would push a new key listener onto the stack, a corresponding menu option would pop it off, and the game loop would only update the listener on the top.